# Open file found using Where-Object

Tags: powershell

I search for a file, e.g. the hosts file:

```
cd c:\Windows\System32
gci -Recurse | ? {$_.Name -eq 'hosts'}
```

Now I want to open the file in `notepad`, so I tried:

```
gci -Recurse | ? {$_.Name -eq 'hosts'} | notepad.exe $_.FullName
```

This errors. Is there a way to do this, as a one-liner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`notepad.exe` does not accept pipeline <strike>output</strike> input

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.Name -eq 'hosts' } |
        Foreach-Object -Process { notepad.exe $_.FullName }
```

> I would recommend using -Filter on get-childitem for this. It would greatly improve performance on the scriptlet.
>   -@matt

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter Hosts -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    ForEach-Object -Process { notepad.exe $_.FullName }
```

Comment: I would recommend using `-Filter` on get-childitem for this. It would greatly improve performance on the scriptlet.

Comment: `notepad.exe` does not accept pipeline *input*.  If validation is only needed on the file's `Name` property, `-Filter` would indeed dramatically increase performance.

Comment: @matt Why is filtering faster than where-object?

Comment: In short, Filter let's the provider handle load so we only get the files we want. Where would still have to process all files